# Counting Water Crossings using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro

I've got a polyline network and i'm trying to calculate the number of water (polygon) crossings for each polyline.

I'd like to end up with a count associated with each unique polyline.

Is there an easy way to do this using ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: The answer will differ between ArcGIS Pro and ArcGIS Desktop 10.0. Which do you want to ask about in this particular question?  What have you tried with that?

Comment: Im using Pro but can also run the model in 10.0.

Comment: Since your question has started to attract ArcGIS Pro answers I've removed ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 from its scope. If you need answers about that too then just ask a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I would perform an intersect of water polygons on the polyline network so you would have only the lines that cover water.

Then you can use the Frequency tool (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/frequency.htm) to count how often the unique ID for the polyline occurs, giving you the number of times that unique polyline crosses the water.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Liam G's answer above, is doing a Spatial Join and adding a field that counts the number of overlapping features by settings the Merge Rule to count. In Pro,k you would right click the layer > Spatial Join to go to the tool dialogue and in ArcMap you would follow this workflow: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008877.